# Opening an Activity from a Fragment in MVP throws a NPE

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-intent, android-activity, mvp

I'm trying to open a new activity from a fragment using MVP but I'm getting a NullPointerException with the following message:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference

This my implementation at the moment

My Presenter

```
public class APIAuthPresenter implements
    GodInterface.setupAuth{
private WeakReference<GodInterface.setupAuth> mView;

public APIAuthPresenter(GodInterface.setupAuth view) {
    mView = new WeakReference<>(view);
}

private GodInterface.setupAuth getView() throws NullPointerException{
    if (mView != null){
        return mView.get();
    }else{
        throw new NullPointerException("View is not available");
    }
}


@Override
public Context getAppContext() {
    try {
        return getView().getAppContext();
    }catch (NullPointerException e)        {
        return null;

    }
}
```

}

The view is passed from the Fragment in the constructor like so

```
public class IGRedirectFragment extends Fragment implements GodInterface.setupAuth {

APIAuthPresenter apiAuthPresenter = new APIAuthPresenter(this);

....

}
```

Then I try to open the activity while inside the presenter

```
getAppContext().startActivity(new Intent(getAppContext(), UserActivity.class));
```

This is my interface class

```
public class GodInterface {
public interface setupAuth{
    String buildURL();
    void requestAccessToken(String code);
    Context getAppContext();
}
}
```

Problem is that I'm getting the NPE exception, I am open to new solutions to solving this as I'm new to MVP.

Comment: What's the implementation of "getAppContext()" on your view?

Comment: The getAppContext() method is implemented in the presenter, you can see the implementation on the first snippet of code

Comment: Where in your code is the `getPackageName()` method, which the error message refers to, called?

Comment: Yes, but it's calling `getView().getAppContext();`, so there's an implementation of `getAppContext()` on your view as well.

Comment: On the view its blank, I'm just returning null

Comment: That's probably your issue. Oh and there's also something I don't get, your presenter and your view implement the same Interface, could it be a mistake?

Comment: OK, I'll try return the context then will update you if it works, No its not a mistake, I have to implement it on my view as well in order to be able to pass the context as the view to the presenter's constructor.

Comment: Mmh, seems a little odd to me... MVP is a way to separate concerns, having both the views and presenter implementing the same interface does not seem to be the best way to do that IMO

Comment: Totally agree with you, thing is I'm not sure of a better way to to it, could you suggest?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135891/discussion-between-ziward-and-noel-omondi).